# Car overheating + new thermostat

Tags: overheating, radiator, renault, thermostat

My Renault 25 has been having cooling problems for several weeks now, yet i cannot figue out the problem.

It has a new thermostat and water pump. Without thermostat, I cannot install a gasket so it simply leaks everywhere but when I refill it while it is idling: radiator, upper radiator hose **and lower radiator** hose heat up. It seems that the car does not overheat without thermostat (yet, i have to add cold water while it is idling).

With the new thermostat installed, it overheats again. However, the radiator and upper radiator hose heat up **while the lower radiator hose does not..** The sides of the radiator also fully heat up, except everything below the lower radiator hose.

---

- Without thermostat, seems to operate normally with a heated lower radiator hose;
- With new (and old) thermostat, heating problems and cold lower radiator hose;
- New water pump

What could be the problem?

Comment: Test the thermostat in boiling water. It should open then close around 185’F

Comment: I Tested that and (unfortunately) it opened..

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! You state it overheats. What are the symptoms of overheating you're seeing? Is it just the dash gauge showing it is overheating, or some other symptoms?

Comment: How quickly does temperature rise to normal? 5 10 or 15 min?  with thermostat installed when the hoses are not pressurized may indicate pump failure.